# Checkbox tree-view

Tags: vmware-clarity

I am new to clarity design. I am trying to implement checkbox treeview. But I am not able to read the values which user selects in treeview i.e, not able to achieve 2-way binding. I am trying to do it using ngModel and ngValue. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to implement `<clr-tree-node [(clrSelected)]="selected">` feature.

If you implement it like shown in the docs with something like the *permissions:* data for the docs for [Selected Tree](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/tree-view) your HTML will look like this:

```
<clr-tree-node
    *ngFor="let permission of permissions"
    [(clrSelected)]="permission.selected">
        {{permission.type}}
    <ng-template [(clrIfExpanded)]="permission.expanded">
        <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let right of permission.rights" [(clrSelected)]="right.enable">
            {{right.name}}
        </clr-tree-node>
    </ng-template>
</clr-tree-node>
```

You can add/use de-sugared syntax for the **clrSelected** @Output like this to check which `tree-node` was selected

```
<clr-tree-node [clrSelected]="selected" (clrSelectedChange)="checkForChanges()">
```

And reduce your permissions down to only the selected nodes in `checkForChanges()`.

### Update

For the permissions array it is easy to filter out the non-selected nodes with this line:

```
permissions.filter(item => item.selected);
```

So, for example lets assume you have a selected property in your component `selected: Array<any> = [];`

Then, your check for changes might look like this

```
checkForChanges() {
    this.selected.length = 0; // clear the selected array
    this.selected = permissions.filter(item => item.selected); // Reduce the array to only selected items.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please provide the code bit to reduce the permissions down to only the selected nodes in checkForChanges() ?

Comment: I updated the answer for the permissions array used in our docs.